# problem in using Sharepoint webservice in iphone

Tags: iphone, sharepoint, ipad, webservice-client

Currently getting this following error:

**You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured to accept.**

i cant able to get the response from the share point server.
Can any one help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check with Apple's developer forums but at some recent point they introduced a bug into their development toolchain that prevented authentication against NTLM protected resources.

Comment: that I don't know...I know was there was a bug reported.  Don't know if they have released a fix or not.